# Why C++/CLI does not support web applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, c++-cli

I spent some time to learn C++/CLI, I feel it is powerful .Net language specially in interoperability concept. I think it will be great step if this language will extend its interoperability to include asp.net, till now the recent version doesn't support asp. But I don't know if there is a plan to do that in future version. Is there any reason that made the last version of C++/CLI can not deal with asp like C# or VB?

Comment: Do you mean ASP.Net WebForms?

Comment: You want to write ASP.NET applications with C++? Why? I mean, seriously, why? You really have to be some kind of a masochist if you want to cause yourself this kind of pain.

Comment: If i am a user of C++\CLI why I need to go and spend time in C# to use asp.net!

Comment: @Adban, if you are a C++ user why do you have to cause the pain to use .NET at all? I mean there gotta be C++ frameworks to write web sites, aren't there? And if you go the .NET way, do it officially and universally: use an appropriate language C#/VB.NET.

Comment: @Darin : I didn't see anyone mention C++; C++ and C++/CLI are two entirely different languages.

Comment: I think that because it is fast way to produce! there are ready classes in C++\CLI not like C++.

Comment: @ildjarn, I agree that C++ and C++/CLI are entirely different languages but I really cannot ever imagine an ASP.NET application written in C++/CLI. That would be a very non-standard beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI was never meant as a general-purpose language. It pretty much exists just for interoperability purposes.

If you have a C/C++ library that you want to use in your .Net application (be it your own code or something like WinAPI), C++/CLI is a good way to either create a managed wrapper for that library or to completely write the whole application, if that's not that much work.

Other than that, you should probably use C# (I think it doesn't make much sense to learn VB.NET if you already know C++). Other alternatives are F# if you think your application would benefit from a functional style. Or IronPython (or IronRuby) if you think you would benefit from dynamic typing.

And of course, you can mix the languages if part of the application would be better in one of them and other part in different one.

Another reasons against using C++/CLI at all are its weak support in VS (no IntelliSense) and the ability of C# to interoperate with native DLLs using P/Invoke.

To reiterate, use C++/CLI if you need to interoperate with native DLLs or already written C/C++ code. For other tasks, you should probably use C#.

Comment: +1 for mentioning F# -- it's my choice over C# 100% of the time.

Comment: the new version of VS  will support C++\CLI IntelliSense

Comment: You missed about five more good reasons to use C++/CLI (such as use of SIMD instructions, or templates which are actually optimized just to name two).  But the overall conclusion is correct -- Use C# for the frontend, a C++/CLI assembly can be referenced and do all the heavy listing.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'm curious, why would you want to use templates in a .Net project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any reason ASP.NET does not natively support C++ inline within aspx files besides the development team didn't think it was worth the cost (I'm assuming this is what you mean).

You should be able to implement code behinds in C++, however. This should get you 95% of the way there, although you'll still need to code your pages in C# or VB.NET.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/helloworldmc.aspx (not my article, just a reference)

Comment: FYI, the linked article uses 'Managed Extensions for C++' syntax, but the OP is asking about C++/CLI.

Comment: Touche. But C++/CLI has access to the FCL and any other .NET aseembly right? This should be all you need?

Comment: Yes, I only meant that the tutorial uses different syntax than what was requested, not that C++/CLI wouldn't be able to achieve the same thing as the article outlines. :-]

Answer (score 0):

The Visual C++ compiler does not support partial class, that is, until C++/CX come along with the help of WinRT projection. The one-obj-file-per-cpp tradition is hard to break.

Without the partial class feature, form designers need to edit the same file you are working on. That means parsing a file with a lot of irrelevant text, dealing with macros, etc, and most importantly avoiding bugs that would replace your important code as designer-generated. I can't think of many teams want to deal with that, especially for small teams like the Settings editor.

Besides, C++ parsers are slower than those for simpler languages. For web designers, if switching to a similair language can get a faster designer and compiler, why not?

Comment: C++ `#include` is MUCH more powerful than partial classes, just incompatible with the designers.

Comment: mmm, how does using a header file solve the problem of isolating designer-generated code to a single file?

Comment: The designer can generate `ref class DesignedForm { #include "DesignedFormCodeBehind.h" /* designed stuff */ };`